# Angular move success recursive callback inside service

Tags: angularjs, recursion, promise, angular-services, angular-http

I have a service that returns $http promises. This works fine, but I need to do a recursive call in case the list returns more than 100 items. Again, this works okay but I'm repeating myself for every controller. I am having trouble offloading the recursion to the service and still getting the end result. Maybe `$q` could help?

```
// service
function List ($http) {
  var headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
    , listService = {
        getByName: function (listName) {
          return $http({
            method: 'GET'
          , url: '/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(\'' + listName + '\')/items'
          , headers: headers
          });
        }

      , getByUrl: function (url) {
          return $http({
            method: 'GET'
          , url: url
          , headers: headers
          })
        }
  };

  return listService;
}

// controller
function Calendar ($scope, List) {
  $scope.events = [];

  List.getByName('Calendar').success(function (response) {
    $scope.events = response.d.results;
    if (response.d.__next) {
      List.getByUrl(response.d.__next).success(recursiveSuccess);
    }
  });

  function recursiveSuccess (response) {
    $scope.events = $scope.events.concat(response.d.results);
    if (response.d.__next) {
      List.getByUrl(response.d.__next).success(recursiveSuccess);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So this doesn't really seem like the proper place to do recursion. I think what you really need is to return the total number of items, either with each call or do a separate call to get that at the start, and then just loop and grab the items in chunks.

Comment: What is your final objective? Do you want to create a service that brings you more-than-100 items while abstracting away the complexity of multiple $http calls?

Comment: @NewDev yes precisely. I just want to move my `then()` logic into the service. I tried a few different things, but I couldn't figure out how to update my controller on the final call, or return just the final call's promise which would have the final result.

Comment: I'm reading [this article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) and will try using $q. I think it's simply a matter of calling `resolve()` once the final call is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each call gives you the next endpoint's URL, this *must* be done in successive HTTP calls. In terms of promises, it would be conceptually done like so:

```
return firstCall.then(function(data){
  return secondCall(data);
})
// another .then
// another .then
.then(function(data){
  return lastCall(data);
});
```

Each `NCall` here is a function that takes the previous call's data and returns a promise for the next aggregated data, and `lastCall` returns the final aggregated data.

If were to convert it into a recursive function, it would look like something below:

```
function getItemsFrom(url, items){

  return $http.get(url).then(function(response){

    items = items.concat(response.data.items);

    if (response.data.next){
      return getItemsFrom(response.data.next, items);
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  });
}
```

with the data being:

```
{
  "next": "url/to/data2.json",
  "items": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

The only thing remaining is the initial call:

```
.factory("fooSvc", function($http){
  function getItemsFrom(url, items){
    // as above
  }

  return {
    getItems: function(){
      return getItemsFrom("url/to/data1.json", []);
    }
  };
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uLBS9NwOZNr1Bi6zU2v9?p=preview)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've had similar problems where I had to do several calls from within a method in my service, and using `$q` solved the problem. It's very powerful once you learn how to use it.

In your service method:

```
function promiseYoullCallMeWhenYoureComplete () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var events = [];

    startMyQuery();

    return deferred.promise;

    ////////////

    function startMyQuery () {
       List.getByName('Calendar').then(success, error);
    }

    function success (response) {
        // perform success actions
        events = angular.extend(events, response.data.d.results);

        // run next query or exit if complete
        if (response.data.next) {
           return startMyQuery();
        }

        // no more queries, so exit and return my combined events array
        return deferred.resolve(events);
    }

    function error (response) {
        return deferred.reject(response);
    }
}
```

And then in your controller, something like:

```
List.promiseYoullCallMeWhenYoureComplete().then(success, error);

///////////

function success (events) {
    $scope.events = events;
}

function error (response) {
    console.error("Error:", response);
}
```

In this way, your service can make $http queries until the cows come home, but your controller will only ever receive a single response to deal with (either a success, which has all the results you pass through your `resolve(...)` method, or error. So your controller is nice and clean, because you can move all that logic into the service.

Comment: You are using a [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) here. From the OP's question it is clear that `List.getByName` returns a promise - there is no need to create a new promise. Just return the promise returned by `startMyQuery`

Comment: Wow very interesting. Thank you very much to you both, I learned a lot.

Comment: @NewDev I disagree with your assessment. Using a `$q` promise gives you certain advantages if you want more control over the behavior of your integration point, ie. forcing a total timeout across the multiple queries.

Comment: @ngDeveloper, there is a way to force a timeout - by timing out the actual HTTP request. Otherwise, the handler of the HTTP request would still execute - a bad practice. Not to mention, that you are forgoing one of the best features of promises - the bubbling up of exceptions.

Comment: ... and revenge-downvoting is also frowned upon. If you have a legitimate reason to downvote, explain why

Comment: @NewDev Here's the case -- if you want more of your code to be located within the Service, so that your controller is cleaner, you do not want to return the response from the $http request directly to the controller. In the case of my app, 1) I have the Service handle a "loading..." spinner on a per-query basis. 2) I also process the response within the Service to prepare a specific error statement to be displayed on the controller, in a catch case, instead of doing that post-response. Also cases where a success response is actually error too. So for a clean Controller, you have to use $q.

Comment: @ngDeveloper, nothing that you mentioned above (unless I misunderstood your case) necessitates or even better solved with another deferred. But, each to his own...